# Could not initialize class org.testng.eclipse.util.ClassMethodsSuite

Tags: java, maven, testng

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.testng.eclipse.util.ClassMethodsSuite
at org.testng.eclipse.util.SuiteGenerator.createCustomizedSuite(SuiteGenerator.java:34)
at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.createLaunchSuites(ConfigurationHelper.java:604)
at org.testng.eclipse.ui.util.ConfigurationHelper.getLaunchSuites(ConfigurationHelper.java:448)
at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.createVMRunner(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:315)
at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launchTypes(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:156)
at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:93)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:862)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:720)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the TestNG Plugin & Reinstall the new one. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled TestNg and reinstalled and now the error is not occurring. Moved Old Eclipse to Trash and used new Instance